# JQuery Jump To Div On Small Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do not know how to explain it in words. I have this website and I want to know how I can jump divs when a small movement is there. Is there a tool out there? Thanks

**EDIT:**

OK so when the user scrolls just slightly with the scroll wheel on their mouse, it should show the next div. I have 4 full page divs and I want to move the scroll wheel just a little bit and it should go to the next div in the proper direction. (Sometimes parallax sites do it. They have the number of divs in dots on the side and you can scroll or click the dot to go to another section/div)

Comment: don't put links to outside personal sites , especially since in this case it does absolutely no good in answering to see your site .  That would be considered spam

Comment: after your edit you completely changed the question , now what you are asking is pretty complex and takes a lot of work with just javascript or jquery.  There are numerous jquery plugins that attempt to you help you out building something like what you want .  I don't think that yuo are going to get someone to write up a complete solution for you.  You are going to have to pick a plugin and give it a shot and see how far you can get and come back with a more specific question along the process

Comment: I found a plugin that is kind of what I am looking for. It is called fullpage.js. I want something like that but with the buttons on the side like dots. I am looking for something like that, not for someone to make it for me.

Answer (score 0):

you are going assign an id to the sections in your page ex

```
<div id="section1" >

</div>
```

doesn't have to be `<div>` , can be any element type

then anywhere on the page make a link , like :

```
< a href="#section1" >   Go To Section 1 </a>
```

Comment: I already have that. I have edited the question trying to explain it better.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you're looking for a combination of jQuery scrollTop() and focus(). Based on scroll position, focus on an element. Note this is bad for accessibility reasons, depending on your user base and needs.